# Troubles managing attributes in python's class

Tags: python

I am a python beginner and it is my first time dealing with OOP. Could you help me to figure out what I am doing wrong whit the code below:

```
class Example(object):

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = self.a + self.b/2

    def property1(self):
        self.obs1 = self.a - self.c

    def property2(self):
        self.obs2 = self.b - self.c


    def get_obs1(self):
        return self.obs1
    def get_obs2(self):
        return self.obs2        

test = Example(2,5)

test.get_obs1()
```

I obtain the following exceptions:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/panadestein/Programming_Games/Python/buggy.py", line 22, in <module>
    test.get_obs1()
  File "/home/panadestein/Programming_Games/Python/buggy.py", line 16, in get_obs1
    return self.obs1
AttributeError: 'Example' object has no attribute 'obs1'
```

Answer (score 0):

As at when `get_obs1` was called the attribute `obs1` was not yet defined and not yet bounded to your class instance. Your question already gives a hint at using `property`, so use this instead and define your *private* variables in `__init__`:

```
class Example(object):

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = self.a + self.b/2
        self._obs1 = self.a - self.c
        self._obs2 = self.b - self.c


    @property
    def obs1(self):
        return self._obs1

    @property
    def obs2(self):
        return self._obs2        

test = Example(2,5)

test.obs1
```

Read more on [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property)